# Getting length of array assigned to extended function prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below will log a, a.length, and b.test. a and b.test both yield [1, 2, 3]. Edit-- I screwed up. b.test yields undefined. See raina's response below.

a.length yields 3.

b.test.length fails with "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Why is this the case when a and b.test are equal?

---

```
var a = [1,2,3];

var b = function(){};

b.prototype.test=[1,2,3];

console.log(a);

console.log(a.length);

console.log(b.test);

console.log(b.test.length);
```

Comment: `console.log(b.test);` prints `undefined`, not `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'm seeing that too now. I must have overlooked something.

Comment: Refer **[How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/572996/500725)** answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `b` does not have `test` property - it's a *function*, and its prototype *object* is `Function.prototype` one.

But objects created with this function will have this property in their prototype chain (as `prototype` *property* of `b` points to the object that has `test` property defined, so this...

```
console.log(new b().test.length);
```

... should give you 3, as expected.